# Message LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method System.Object Get(Int32, Int32) method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to get a List from Linq to entity-query

```
List<int> meas_i = wc.measures
   .Where(meas => meas.shortname == (valueArray[i, 8] ?? "").ToString())
   .Select(meas => meas.idmeasure)
   .ToList<int>();
```

But after the execution I obtain the following exception (not suppported) message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in ComplexWorkWinDraw.exe
>
> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Object Get(Int32, Int32)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

Please help. Thanks to all

Answer (score 4):

Try to store this in a variable before the query: `valueArray[i, 8]`

```
string shortName = (valueArray[i, 8] ?? "").ToString();

List<int> meas_i = wc.measures
   .Where(meas => meas.shortname == shortName)
   .Select(meas => meas.idmeasure)
   .ToList<int>();
```

Everything in this query must be translated to SQL. But since this value is not related to the record/item you can store it in a separate variable before the query.

Comment: That is all right. Thank you very  much